# Alamofire - Image Upload fails when using photos

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire, multipart

Dear stackoverflow community,

I'm working at an iOS App which uses Alamofire to send a JSON along with images to a REST API. The images are retrieved with an image picker and stored in an array. The problem is, that the image upload works as long as I use downloaded images from the internet, etc. Once I try to upload a photo, which was taken with the phone I'm currently using (selected from the photo library) the upload fails and throws a 400 - Bad Request error. The odd thing is, that when I can upload photos, that have been taken from another iPhone, but were sent to me, but photos, which were taken with the phone itself are not working... Does someone have an idea why this problem occurs? I have a suspicion, that the format or the data of iPhone photos might be different from downloaded ones, because of HDR and other stuff, but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Here is the code I use, its pretty standard though:

```
func POST_WITH_ATACHMENTS(description: String, attachments: [UIImage], returnCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let parameters = ["ticket":"{ \"description\" : \"" + description + "\"}"]

    APIManager.Manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8)!), withName: key, mimeType: "application/json")
        }

        var counter = 1
        for image in attachments {
            multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, withName: "attachments", fileName: "attachment" + String(counter) + ".png", mimeType: "image/png")
            counter += 1
        }
    },
                     to: restURL!,
                     method: .post,
                     headers:["Authorization" : loginString],
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                                if (upload.response?.statusCode == 201) {
                                    returnCompletion(true)
                                } else {
                                    returnCompletion(false)
                                }
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                            returnCompletion(false)
                        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Try by using `image/jpeg` as mime type. Because this is common to most of image formats like `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.jfif`.

Comment: I tried your solution and found out, that it depends on the size of the image I think... if I set the resize factor to 0.5 the photo upload works, but uncompressed it fails.... weird, the server probably doesnt support images that big. thanks!

Comment: There is an option available for streaming your content in `Alamofire`. Have a look into it. May be useful to upload large size image.

Comment: @RobertBarta Use my method to upload image using AlamoFire

Answer (score 0):

Here is webservice for uploading image using AlamoFire

```
class WebServiceHandler: AnyObject {

    func uploadWithAlamofire(Parameters params : [NSObject : AnyObject]?,ImageParameters imgparams :  [NSObject : AnyObject]?,Action action : NSString, success: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void, failure: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void)
    {
        var base_url = "YOUR BASE_URL"
        base_url.append(action as String)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if imgparams != nil{
                for (key, value) in imgparams! {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value as! UIImage, 1) {
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: key as! String, fileName: "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                    }
                }
            }

            if params != nil
            {
                for (key, value) in params! {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key as! String)
                }

            } }, to: base_url, method: .post, headers: nil,
                 encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.uploadProgress { progress in
                            print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                        }
                        upload.response { [weak self] response in
                            guard self != nil else {
                                return
                            }
                            let responseString = String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                            return success(responseString as AnyObject)

                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print("error:\(encodingError)")
                        return failure(encodingError as AnyObject)
                    }
        })
    }
    func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


----------------------------USAGE-----------------------------

let dict_params = NSMutableDictionary()
dict_params.set("123", forKey:"YourKey")
dict_params.set("123", forKey:"YourKey")
.
.
.and so on

let imgparam = NSMutableDictionary()
imgparam.set(YourImagetoUpload, forKey: "YourKey")
//here YourImagetoUpload is like imageview.image or UIImage(named: "123.png")
imgparam.set(YourImagetoUpload, forKey: "YourKey")
.
.
.and so on


self.webservice.uploadWithAlamofire(Parameters: dict_params as [NSObject : AnyObject], ImageParameters: imgparam as [NSObject : AnyObject], Action: "API_ACTION_CALL", success: { (success) in
        print(success)
}) { (error) in
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The method is similar to mine, so I think the problem really lies server side, where the REST API doesn't support images that big, I might try the suggested stream version, or scale the images down, since they don't need to be in full resolution for my project.